# Cannot build module in OS x mavericks - Titanium TermiT ZipFile

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, titanium, appcelerator, zip

I used module at this link :
https://github.com/TermiT/ZipFile

But When we run this file (build.py) fallowing the I take error

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/ZipFile.build/Release-iphoneos/zipfile.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ZipfileModule.o Classes/ZipfileModule.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and while searching it turned out that we're missing the GCC compiler, here's a link for what I've found, https://github.com/TermiT/ZipFile/issues/15 , and it also have a link to download the GCC compiler.